# Replace "%s" in a variable with a variable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a file transfer.txt with the following content:

```
<RECORD1>DATA</RECORD1>
<RECORD2>%s</RECORD2>
```

I am reading this file in my python program as:

```
with open ("../config/transferxml.txt", "r") as myfile:
    xmldata=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
```

Now I have the file contents as a string in my variable. I want to replace the '%s' in xmldata with a vairable. For instance I've tried:

```
xmldatawithvariable=(xmldata, %(requestid))
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Get rid of the superfluous punctuation (and add some white space): `xmldatawithvariable = xmldata % requestid`. Also, as a rule, providing *the actual traceback* can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You just used the incorrect syntax for string formatting. Use this instead:

```
python
>>> s = 'hello %s'
>>> t = s % ('world')
>>> t
'hello world'
```

For your code that means using:

```
xmldatawithvariable = xmldata % (requestid)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `%` :

```
>>> x='<RECORD1>DATA</RECORD1><RECORD2>%s</RECORD2>'
>>> x%10
'<RECORD1>DATA</RECORD1><RECORD2>10</RECORD2>'
>>> x%'VAL'
'<RECORD1>DATA</RECORD1><RECORD2>VAL</RECORD2>'
```